# Loading an MVC site

Tags: model-view-controller, publishing

Hello I am in desperate need of help. I just created an MVC site made in Visual Web Developer 2010
and each time and on different Web Hosts I get --Index of /-- instead of the site loading properly. It's as if the server or browser is looking for an 'index' file instead of being routed through the MVC folders to the proper start up page. I've done everything I believe I am suppose to do as far bring all my dll 'system' files to the 'bin' folder as well as everything else including getting a Web Host that has MVC supporting server but I still keep getting 'Index of /' and the folders instead of the site. Can anyone help? I'm really in a spot. I've been working on this site for months and I need to get it up and running.

Thanks, Rob

Comment: have you tried to publish on localhost is it working on your local iis

Comment: yes. It works on the local host.

Comment: Have you checked that the app pool is set to .net 4 on the host?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your default route is not setup or the setup is pointed to a place that doesn't exist. Your default route will be in the default.asax.cs page (MVC4 is App_Start/RouteConfig.cs) and looks something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "",        // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}  // Parameter defaults
    );
```

So the the Default action is Home/Index. You can change this if you want to redirect to a different default page.